# Is there a way to record maximum memory used running in PERL

Tags: perl, memory

As I said, I want to record the max memory used during program run time.

Comment: What memory? Total system RAM used, or memory used by the perl script itself, or the memory used by some other application?

Comment: Once allocated, perl does not release memory back to the operating system until the process ends. In that sense, it is sufficient to measure the memory usage just before your program exits.

Comment: You can look at `ps` output (or `top`) to get a general idea.  The issue is usually the memory used by shared libraries associated with a process; viz. to which process(es) do you "charge" the memory usage.

Comment: I mean the memory used by the perl script itself

Comment: @mob, That's not true. It depends on the allocator your build uses. The Windows typically used on Windows returns blocks to the system. At least the large ones.

Comment: @lolibility - do you mean memory used by the Perl interpreter? Or heap+stack memory allocated to running the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Devel::Size` only measures the memory size one at a time for one particular data structure to measure the total memory size of all data structure used in your script On Unix-like systems, `Proc::ProcessTable` provides a nice API for it:

Here is a simple script, comparing it with Devel::Size.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Proc::ProcessTable;
use Devel::Size qw(size);


my @arr = ('A' .. 'M');
my $devel_size = size(\@arr);
print "With DEVEL::SIZE I'm $devel_size bytes big\n";


my $t = Proc::ProcessTable->new();

foreach my $p ( @{$t->table} ) {
    if($p->pid() == $$) {
    print "With Proc::ProcessTable I'm ", $p->size(), " bytes big.\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

It gives:

With `DEVEL::SIZE` I'm 104 bytes big. 
With `Proc::ProcessTable` I'm 5357568 bytes big.

**Note:** source of Info: http://www.perlmonks.org/

Answer (score 0):

Found this on perlmonks, http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=498401:

```
use Devel::Size qw/ total_size /;
print total_size( \%:: );
```